# Marketplace App Search URI parameters: Is there any way to invoke Safe Search or its equivalent?

Tags: search, google-play

I'm developing a mobile app that links to search result pages in the Android Marketplace app, but I want to avoid returning any *adult* related content. The only valid search URI parameters that I can find are:

```
"details?id=<package_name>"
"search?q=<query>"
"search?q=pub:<publisher_name>"
```

I think it's pretty weird that Google doesn't offer an option for Safe Search in the Marketplace app, as their web-based Marketplace supports it and the base URI structure is identical to the app's.

I created a small [web page](http://www.xyzzy.t15.org/index.html) with sample URLs that demonstrate the issue. All of the examples work on the Android Marketplace web site, but only the last example works in the app.

If Google doesn't offer any URI parameters that invoke Safe Search (and it appears they don't), can you think of any possible work-arounds?

I don't want kids searching for a term like "bears" and stumbling across something like [this](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.initechapps.growlr). [not safe for work]

...which, just for the record, is currently the 9th result of 2,079 matches for that search term.

---

The Marketplace app has a setting for content filtering (in four levels, just like Safe Search). Is it possible that the app parses all externally-called URIs and replaces any Safe Search parameters with its own? After all, I shouldn't be able to override the app's settings. This activity would most-likely take place on the client side (it almost has to), so packet sniffing via a WiFi connection may yield some clues.

Comment: Interesting (and well-worded!) question, mate! I guess you'll have to resort to sniffing the marketplace app's traffic. Please post your findings here, though!